# How to add facebook sdk login to an eureka swift form?

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I am currently developing an iOS app with Swift, I had already downloaded facebok sdk login and also I am familiar with it. In the other hand I need to make custom table views so I downloaded Eureka framework to do this.

I have a table that asks the user for information in order to register a new account, the problem is that I need a facebook login option at the top of the table view, but I havent find a way to accomplish this. As the Eureka table view is added programmatically it can be seen in the storyboard so I need to find a a way and add the login button. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Here is my table code:

```
private func addLoginForm() {
        self.form +++ Section()
            <<< TextRow() { $0.placeholder = "Name"
                $0.tag = "name"
            }
            +++ Section()
            <<< TextRow() { $0.placeholder = "Email"
                $0.tag = "email"
            }
            +++ Section()
            <<< PhoneRow() {$0.placeholder = "Phone"
                $0.tag = "phone"
            }
            +++ Section()
            <<< PasswordRow() { $0.placeholder = "Password"
                $0.tag = "password"
            }
            +++ Section()
            <<< ButtonRow() {
                $0.title = "Login"
                $0.onCellSelection { cell, row in

                    self.evaluate()

                    }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 114.0/255, green: 3.0/255, blue: 194.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                        cell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                        row.cell.height = {
                            return  65
                        }
                    })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded the solution by adding the facebook login at the header of a section in the form like this:

```
   form  +++ Section()
            {
                var header = HeaderFooterView<FBSDKLoginButton>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
                header.onSetupView = { (view: FBSDKLoginButton, section: Section) -> Void in
                     view.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]
                     view.delegate = self
                }

                $0.header = header
        }
```

also you need to import FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKCoreKit

Answer (score 0):

You could add a header to the table view instead of the section.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    ...

    if let tableView = tableView {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = yourFBHeaderView
    }

    ...
}
```